# Is there a tool that helps moving .cs files depending on the type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, refactoring, resharper

I'm doing some refactoring on a big project that have two types of testing projects: Unit and Integration. The Unit testing projects are supposed to have tests that inherits UnitTest class, and the Integration testing projects, tests that inherit IntegrationTest. The problem now, is that in "Unit" there are some files that are "Integration" tests, and vice versa. Do you know a way to "easily" move files and keep the configuration in a way that the tests still runs?

I created a batch, and it moved the files correctly. The problem is that the .csproj doesn't update automatically and also that the're some classes that are not tests, but that are used by the tests. (Mock up classes for example).

Comment: Just select files in solution explorer, then do Ctrl-X, select folder which you want them to be moved (also in solution explorer) and Ctrl-V. Projects will be updated automatically

Comment: Yeah, but I'm there are more than 2,000 files and like... 20 projects, so I was wondering if a tool can help me to do this programatically

Comment: No tool I know of. Test maintenance is largely a manual operation, especially when someone messes up and mixes test types. NOTE: I am muddling through the same issue right now.

Comment: What I was thinking is on changing the namespace to the "correct one" that one is easy, but then... how could you move files to the right place and leave the configuration in order? for example, the .csproj need an update :/. Btw, I have a batch file that moves the .cs files to the correct directory -or project- but the problem is also how to update .csproj and also, how to update dlls required :(